# Difficulty on reading JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm sending this JSON already parsed to a PHP script:

```
{
"date" : "03/12/2013",
"services" :    [
                    {"0" :  [
                            {"technician" : "ALEX "},
                            {"os" : [
                                    {"0" :  [
                                            {"num_service" : "1213607"},
                                            {"destiny" : "Lucelia,SP"}
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    {"0" :  [
                                            {"num_service" : "1213409"},
                                            {"destiny" : "Santos,SP"}
                                            ]
                                    }
                                    ]
                            }
                            ]
                    },
                    {"1" :  [
                            {"technician" : "NIVALDO"},
                            {"os" : [
                                    {"0" :  [
                                            {"num_service" : "1213631"},
                                            {"destiny" : "Lupionopolis,PR"}
                                            ]
                                    }
                                    ]
                            }
                            ]
                    }
                ]
```

}`

What i need is to create a string composed by the 'num_service' columns separated by comma. Like this way:

"1213607,1213409,1213631"

I'm trying with each loops but without success. This is what i've tried:

```
foreach($_POST['json']['services'] as $array1){
foreach($array1 as $array2){
    foreach($array2[1]['os'] as $array3){
        var_dump($array3[0]);
        foreach($array4 as $array5){
            $todas_os .= $array5[0][0]['num_service'] . ",";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Would someone help me please?

Comment: You need to decode it with `json_decode`.

Comment: "I'm sending this JSON already parsed to a PHP script" what do you mean by this?  If you've already parsed it, do a `print_r()` on your object.  JSON has nothing to do with your question.  If you haven't parsed it, then please clarify the first sentence in your question.

Comment: I meant that before sending the json via ajax, i make a the string and then i use the 'JSON.parse' function on that string, then i send via ajax

Comment: Instead of only showing us the raw JSON that "should be passed" to the script in its unparsed form, why not `var_dump($_POST['json']);` so we can see what PHP is actually getting?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I resolved my problem by following your tips.

First, i'm not parsing the json before sending to the PHP script anymore. I'm sending the json structured string via AJAX. And yes, the json is valid.

On PHP, i'm using the json_decode() function and using the returned object to access it's data.

Now i've learned that this is the right way. Thanks for the everyone's help.